# Multiple conditons withColumn perfomance recomendations

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here is my code. I get the right output but i takes forever and I feel like I'm repeating myself way too many times.

My question is there another way of checking the database rows for the conditions I ask?

Thank you in advance for the recommendations

```
Output = (db.withColumn('Puhelin', F.when(F.col('source_browser_platform')=='Android OS' ,F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('0')))
     .withColumn('Puhelin', F.when(F.col('source_browser_platform')=='iOS',F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('0')))
     .withColumn('Puhelin', F.when(F.col('source_browser_platform')=='OS/2',F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('0')))
     .withColumn('Puhelin', F.when(F.col('source_browser_platform')=='Windows Mobile',F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('0')))
     .withColumn('Puhelin', F.when(F.col('source_browser_platform')=='Chrome OS',F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('0')))
     .withColumn('Puhelin', F.when(F.col('source_browser_platform')=='BlackBerry OS',F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('0')))
     .withColumn('Puhelin', F.when(F.col('source_browser_platform')=='Windows XP',F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('0')))
     .withColumn('Tietokone', F.when(F.col('source_browser_platform')=='Windows 10',F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('0')))
     .withColumn('Tietokone', F.when(F.col('source_browser_platform')=='Windows 8',F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('0')))
     .withColumn('Tietokone', F.when(F.col('source_browser_platform')=='Windows 8.1',F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('0')))
     .withColumn('Tietokone', F.when(F.col('source_browser_platform')=='Mac OS',F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('0')))
     .withColumn('Tietokone', F.when(F.col('source_browser_platform')=='Linux',F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('0')))
     .withColumn('Tietokone', F.when(F.col('source_browser_platform')=='Windows 2000',F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('0')))
     .withColumn('Tietokone', F.when(F.col('source_browser_platform')=='Windows Server 2003',F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('0')))
     .withColumn('Tietokone', F.when(F.col('source_browser_platform')=='Sun OS',F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('0')))
     .withColumn('Tietokone', F.when(F.col('source_browser_platform')=='Windows Vista',F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('0')))
     .withColumn('Tietokone', F.when(F.col('source_browser_platform')=='Open BSD',F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('0')))
     .withColumn('Tietokone', F.when(F.col('source_browser_platform')=='Windows 7',F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('0')))
    )
```

Comment: It seems you're trying to check whether the platform is mobile or desktop, but in the way you're writing it, it will only check whether it is windows xp or windows 7 because you're overwriting the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isin` to check whether a column is in a given list:

```
puhelin_list = ['Android OS', 'iOS', ...]
tietokone_list = ['Windows 10', 'Windows 8', ...]

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

output = db.withColumn(
    'puhelin', F.col('source_browser_platform').isin(puhelin_list).cast('int')
).withColumn(
    'Tietokone', F.col('source_browser_platform').isin(tietokone_list).cast('int')
)
```